# Error OpenGL null Cocos-2D/Visual Studio

Tags: opengl, cocos2d, visual-studio

When I try to execute a game code fully functional on Visual Studio 2013, using Cocos-2D (3.8.1) library this error jumps on screen. (I'm working on a laptop)

[image: Error Window 1]

> OpenGL 1.5 or higher is required (your version is (null)). Please upgrade the driver of your video card.

And then this one:

[image: Error Window 2]

My Graphic card is an AMD Radeon HD 7600M (OpenGL version 4.x), with de drivers fully updated.

Neither my college teacher nor me know how to fix it.

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What cpu does your laptop have? Does it have onboard graphics?
This happend to me where any apps I opened used the onboard graphics (Intel HD 3000). Through some intel control panel I was able to tell it to use the geForce graphics card by default instead of the HD 3000.

Comment: I thought that too, but my laptop uses by default the AMD graphic card (I don't know if Visual Studio doses). The CPU is an Intel i7-3630 with 2.4GhHz.

Comment: What model is your laptop? And what model CPU does it have?

Comment: A Toshiba Satellite L850
The CPU is an Intel i7-3630 with 2.4GhHz.

Comment: Have you tried setting the app you compile to high performance in the catalyst control centre? Check [this site](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19474269) out.